# Create background right of heading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to convert PSD to HTML/CSS template.
**I wanted to put that background to the right of the text but I failed.**

Here is my code right now :

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="block-main">
    <div class="block-title">
      <h4>SUBSCRIBE NOW</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Button image]

Comment: Can you provide your CSS code? Ideally create a stack snippet or jsfiddle demo.

Comment: Do you need it to be a background-image? Otherwise you could just use an image and `display: inline` in the CSS

Comment: @WilliamBrochmann I think `img` tags are `inline` by default

Comment: @Aziz Yes but the `h4` is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pseudo-element and flexbox

```css
h4 {
  display: flex;
}

h4::after {
  content: '';
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  -45deg,
  gray,
  gray 6px,
  black 6px,
  black 12px
    );
  flex:1;
  margin-left: 1em; /* for spacing only */
}
```

```html
<h4>SUBSCRIBE NOW</h4>
```

Comment: I was trying to do the stripes part using css linear-gradient , but  couldnt find a way , so i used as background image the striped part . Thank you !

Comment: Updated with gradient stripes.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `img` tag and set the `h4`'s CSS to `display:inline;`, like so:

```css
h4 {
  display: inline;
}
img {
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h4>Text here</h4>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXQgo.png">
</div>
```

Comment: This also seems to work well . Thanks for helping me !